# Abrir arquivo com input de usuário em assembly NASM x86

Tags: arquivo, input, assembly

Estou tentando abrir um arquivo que foi expecificado por um input do usuário em assembly, com o seguinte código

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:

    ; Perguntar o nome do arquivo para abrir
    mov eax,4
    mov edx,size1
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,firstMessage

    int 80h

    ; Receber o nome do arquivo
    mov eax,3
    mov edx,8 ; Precisa ser exatamente 8 se o arquivo for text.txt, impossibilitando livre arbítrio do usuário
    mov ebx,2
    mov ecx,fileName

    int 80h

    ; Abrir o arquivo
    mov eax,5
    mov ebx,fileName
    mov ecx,0
    mov edx,0777

    int 80h

    ; Mover o file decriptor para a variável buf
    mov [buf],eax

    ; Ler o arquivo
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,[buf]
    mov edx,11
    mov ecx,info

    int 80h

    ; Sys_call para printar o valor na tela
    mov eax,4
    mov edx,11
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,info

    int 80h

    ; Sair do programa
    mov eax,1
    int 80h

section .data
    firstMessage db "Type the filename to read:",0xA
    size1 equ $-firstMessage
section .bss
    fileName resb 20
    info resb 11
    buf resw 1
```

O problema é que para funcionar eu preciso ler a quantidade exatas de letras do arquivo que precisa ser aberto, tipo : text.txt 8, caso eu leia 9 e o usuário continue colocando "text.txt" o arquivo não é aberto com sucesso, como se um byte que não foi preenchido fizesse diferença na hora de abrir um arquivo.

Alguma maneira de tirar esses bytes desnecessários?